# Edit Suhosin Config Parameters

Tags: php, nginx, amazon-ec2, webserver, suhosin

We have an Amazon EC2 instance running Ubuntu LEMP installation (nginx). We would like to modify several suhosin config parameters. We tried changing the parameters in /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/suhosin.ini file, but it won't change the values. Upon loading phpinfo function, we still see the old default values. We also added the parameters into /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini file (which is the file parsed by the nginx web server) to no avail.

nginx was restarted each time after making the above changes and php-fpm was also restarted. However, we cannot change the default values of any of the suhosin parameters.

Which file needs to be edited here?

Answer (score 1):

`phpinfo()` lists directories for .ini files, e.g.:

```
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /foo/bar
Additional .ini files parsed => /foo/bar/php.ini
```

Any of these ini files or a new ini file in the scan path may be used to set suhosin options.

Note: Later occurrence of the same option has precedence.